# AS3 protected is clobbered?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, inheritance, static, instance

I have a joyful Flash AS3 conundrum. Given the following code:

```
public class BaseClass
{
  protected var _A:uint;
}

public class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass
{
  public static function readBaseA(a:BaseClass) : uint
  {
    return a._A;
  }
}
```

So you see, the static function is using its ability to read the protected member of BaseClass, to return _A.

But this does not compute, and Flash barks back at me with:

```
(hidden)\ExtendedClass.as, Line 7   1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property _A through a reference with static type BaseClass.
```

In Java, this is okay. And I consider Java the reference implementation of basic OO.

if I take away the 'static' from that readBaseA method, so that now it is an instance method, I still cannot read the _A from a BaseClass instance. But interestingly, I can read it from this._A.

It's like AS3 is differentiating between this's protected members, and other objects' protected members, although those objects may be instances of the same class as 'this'.

Anyone seen similar behaviour out there in the wild?

Rich

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but yes this is how AS works. Whether it is "wrong" or not is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3):

`_A` is protected so it can only be accessed from within the same class or it's sub-classes, and since it's not declared as static "class" in this regard actually means "class instance".

To clarify, an instance `a` cannot access a private or protected property of instance `b`, regardless of whether they have the exact same type or if one extends the other.

Comment: He's passing an instance into the static method. So if the '_A' property were public this would actually work.

Comment: It is a contrived example, but makes sense when you replace BaseClass, ExtendedClass and _A with my real names.

richardollson in other more reputable languages (like Java) this is allowed, even inside a static function where there is no this.

Comment: @RichColours, but you already knew all that, so it seems your post was not a question but pointless comments and rants about ActionScript and Java.

Comment: @Laurent my question was "Anyone seen similar behaviour out there in the wild?".

So I was hoping for knowledgable people confirming that the behaviour goes against general OO understanding and literature, OR that what I wanted to do was achieveable but I was using AS3 wrong.

If I were Adobe, i'd have documented HOW my language worked when it strayed away from the general understanding of a language feature. But they haven't. Specifically, why in a static function in B (which extends A), can one not see the protected variables of a parameter of type A.

Comment: I believe that, in things like this, Adobe sticks to the ECMAScript standard, which may not be identical to how Java implemented it.  The way protected works in AS is definitely documented.

Comment: @RichColours, you write that but you obviously haven't read the documentation. It's explicitly written that "The definition of protected in ActionScript 3.0 is more restrictive than that of protected in the Java programming language. In ActionScript 3.0 protected limits access strictly to subclasses.". http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#protected So yes - AS3 != Java, you don't expect every language on the planet to be like Java, do you?

Comment: @Laurent Let's dissect that documentation.

My use of protected is on an instance var in A, and B is a subclass of A. They are in the same package. So lets forget the package issue, it doesn't come into play here. You've clearly picked up on the word Java in that doc and have got a little fixated on it.

My (static) function readBaseA() is a function in a subclass of A, and A is where the protected var is defined. Now, what part of that document says that it is not available in my context? It mentions nothing of static whatsoever.

Comment: A language spec doesn't have to document what the language doesn't do. They wrote "protected limits access **strictly** to **subclasses**". It's as clear as it can get. It implies, among others, that protected members of **class instances** (class instances != subclasses) are not accessible, whether it's from the same class or a different class, whether it's from a static member or not, etc. "Strictly" here means "with no exceptions".

Comment: Mate, protected instance vars are available to code in the same class. That's a given.

I'm not sure how you understand my little bit of code. Do you think that ExtendedClass is a subclass of BaseClass or not? Clue: it is. So, code in ExtendedClass really ought to be able to see protected variables of superclasses.

"A language spec doesn't have to document what the language doesn't do." seems to be something we agree on :-)

Comment: @RichCoulors: I agree that the linked document does not explicitly say that what you're trying to do isn't possible, because it speaks of classes only (disregarding the topic of instances.) This is a definite shortcoming. I've also had a look through the actual specification at the URL below, which also neglects to explain this. However, the bottom line is that ActionScript works this way. Whether or not that's "good" is a matter of opinion. http://livedocs.adobe.com/specs/actionscript/3/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=as3_specification.html

Answer (score 3):

it'll work if you use `internal` instead of `protected` instance property. (if that is enough privacy for you)

ActionScript is very particular about what `protected` means, from Adobe:

> "`protected` - Visible to references in the same class and derived classes."

So its only available to references specifically, and unfortunately in your case, they obviously mean instance references only. This might have something to do with the prototype-based implementation that ActionScript is built on, where its only checking the `prototype` object and not the `constructor` object to determine if access is allowed protected member.

Comment: I'm about to give up with "encapsulation" and make the whole bloody thing public, and get this project out the door! Sodding language.

Comment: I agreed, I actually ran into a similar problem a few months ago, and I was able to to hide the property uisng `internal` because the base class and all of the inherited classes were in a very specific package, so for me `internal` and `protected` happened to provide a very similar scope for what I was doing. Coming from C#  that wasn't the way that I expected to have to do it.

Answer (score 2):

that's how it works in AS3:

```
public class BaseClass
{
  protected var _A:uint;
}

public class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass
{
  public function readBaseA() : uint
  {
    return super._A;
  }
}
```

`protected` fields can be accessed and overriden from extended classes and are treated as `private` for any other case

Comment: readBaseA() is static on ExtendedClass.

So how can super._A be accessing an instance, if readBaseA() is static?

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/specs/actionscript/3/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=as3_specification.html details how super and this cannot be used in a static function.

Comment: @RichColours - it was a stupid copy-paste error, fixed my answer

Comment: At this point, you could make readBaseA() private, and access _it_ with static functions (in the same class) for an equivalent level of information hiding.